# Change Label Content prop from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have form with `Label` and `Slider`.

I am trying to change `Label.Content` by getting value from **ViewModel** property.
Also, I update that value in **ViewModel** using `Slider`, but when I change slider value, property updates, but I can't see updated value at `Label`. `Content` have that value, which was after running program.

### Here is `xaml` code:

```
<Slider 
    Value="{Binding MathLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="200" />
<Label
    Content="{Binding MathLevel}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="157,250,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

### Property in ViewModel

```
public int MathLevel
{
    get => user.Skills [0].Level;
    set {
        user.Skills [0].Level = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Math skill level");
    }
}
```

### And here User.cs

```
 class User
 {
     public List<Skill> Skills {get;set;} = new List<Skill>();
 }
```

I just want to change `Content` on `Label` to value from property `MathSkill`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem in the OnPropertyChanged() call. It should have the name of the property to update in the quotes

```
public int MathLevel
{
    get => user.Skills [0].Level;
    set
    {
        user.Skills [0].Level = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MathLevel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Safer to call `OnPropertyChanged(() => this.MathLevel);` so that the compiler warns you of any spelling mistakes.